# Working with TIFF in Python using EasyOCR

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tiff, easyocr

I use a Python Module EasyOCR for extracting text from image. This Method works for PNG Format but in TIFF Situation give me a error

Code look like this:

```
import easyocr 
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

IMAGE_PATH = 'IMG_4022.tif'

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext(IMAGE_PATH)
result
```

I work with Juypter Notebook

Comment: Please provide the details of the error.

Comment: @fam error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading the image. Please use `opencv` to read the image. Ensure that the image is in the current directory or provide the absolute path of the image.

```
from easyocr import Reader 
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

IMAGE_PATH = "IMG_4022.tif"
image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)

languages = ['en']

reader = Reader(languages, gpu = False)
results = reader.readtext(image)
```